# Free alternatives to include maps into my Cordova project besides Google Maps

Tags: cordova, geolocation, maps

I'm using cordova geolocation to receive coordinates from a DB and I want to show it on a map.

I saw that, now, Google requires a billing account to allow create api keys to include it into my cordova or web projects.

What are the best alternatives to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use google maps without billing verification. but we have few alternative ways to integrate maps with app

- https://www.mapbox.com/
- https://www.mapfit.com/

Here is a Cordova plugin for MapBox: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Mapbox

But these services are not perfect as Google Map platform. Google Maps is just need a verification to use their service. They do have free limitation, please check pricing: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Comment: Thank you, but im trying openstreetmap and until now, it seems to be the solution.